# echo and UTF-8 (PHP)

Tags: php, utf-8

I have installed Apache on my server (I wasn't using Apache) and special characters started to show wrong.

So I changed every file to UTF-8, configured MySQL to work with UTF-8 and everything worked fine. However, my Python app (which retrieves some information from the website) doesn't work properly.

For example, I had a file "test.php" which returned either 0 or 1. Python code then did whatever with that result.

But now, my Python app doesn't receive "0", I don't know what it gets from the website. I made the app send a GET request to my site with what it was getting and it sent me this: "???0".

What can I do? I tried to change the header to send the result as ISO-8859-1 (as it was before) but isn't working either.

Comment: how about showing us the code that is generating that strange reply? And inspecting that source file for strange chars?

Comment: if (mysql_num_rows($mixIDq) > 0) {
   $mixinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($mixIDq);
   $mixID = $mixinfo['mix_id'];
   
   $mix = new mix($mixID);
   $team = $mix->getTeamFromSteam($stmid);
   $team += 2;
   
   echo $team;
  } else {
   echo "0";
  }

Comment: Is the byte order mark (BOM) enabled on any of your files? That could be including a single weird character before any other output.

Comment: That is the code, that is why I said it's really weird. I'm just echoing "0" or the other result

Comment: try forcing your text editor to save the source file -without- [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark).

Comment: I wonder if those question marks are some kind of newlines before the `echo()`?

Comment: @Ivan: code is unreadable in comments, edit your question. And do look very closely at the source file (using a hex editor if necessary) to find strange chars.

Comment: It is indeed the BOM. However, it seems that Apache is attaching it before sending the response, because I added header("Location: index.php") to see if headers were already sent (BOM should have been shown already) and it worked properly.

Comment: OK I finally solved it. I was including a file, which was also including a file, which had the BOM. I saved it without BOM and it is working now properly.
The header was working because I sent the header before including the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) symbol. Remove this symbol from script in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) editor (Menu -> Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM).